# magento calls home?

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

If you have a look at their website it shows statical data

```
$25 Billion in transactions

60,000+ merchants

2,000+ extensions

2+ Million downloads
```

**EDIT:** just wanted to know where does magento get its data from!?

Comment: Why, just last week my marketing department stated we'd had $25b in revenue. It's not like they could just be extrapolating data (or lying), is it? You haven't yet shown the connection between A and B and you want us to tell you how to stop B (presuming that it is true). I think that's called a logical fallacy. Voting to close as "not a real question" because "paranoid delusion" was not one of the options :-)

Comment: So where does the numbers come from? its $25b not $20b or $30b, how does it know its $25b? if magneto is estimating it should state that its an estimate, otherwise its going to be taken as accurate figures.

Answer (score 2):

Often numbers like these are sort of accurate guesstimates done by canvassing users. You should take this up with them directly, I'm sure they'll be happy to help.

Making wild claims like this without proof is also a good way to get sued for libel, btw.

Comment: I don't think they can sue you for posing a legitimate question. The question makes sense. I always wanted to know from where the marketing people get data that is so precise without a source :)

Comment: The first assertion (that magento "calls home") is what a company could object to. The question the user wanted to ask (how do they get this data) is indeed an interesting question. I've done some economic modelling, basically you guess.

Answer (score 0):

Magento code is open source, meaning you can take a look at it any time. I worked with Magento for 3 months and I didn't notice any pingbacks and generally in open source projects developers avoid pingbacks. Especially in a eCommerce environment this could be a security breach and a potential source of information leakage. I assume Magento data are estimates and not real data provided by any monitoring tools in the code.

Magento is using [OSL](http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php) licence.